Spryker join query
i am started learning spryker and facing some issue i have below query for my console command in the repository file like
$pyzABCMappingQuery =  new PyzABCMappingQuery();
$resultset  = $pyzABCMappingQuery
                ->filterByVinNumber("SOME VALUE")->find();

but i have to fetch the record than run for each loop to find data from second table
with logic that Pyz_ABC_Mapping tables field1 concatenate with underscore and than field2 and than this value match with  Pyz_PQR_table field3 like this
Pyz_ABC_Mapping.field1."_".Pyz_ABC_Mapping.field2 == Pyz_PQR_table.field3 

but  i want to do this using join in spryker is it possible than how to do it
Thanks
